# Load files from Assets folder in webview

Tags: android, webview, assets

I have a webview in my android app, the html file which gets loaded is on a server, however I need to address some files from app's assets folder. I wanted to ask how can I address those files.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ViewWeb extends Activity {  
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);  
        WebView wv;  
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);  
        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/aboutcertified.html");   // now it will not fail here
    }  
}
```

And in general you can use 
    getAssets().open("filename.txt"))
To get filea from assets
On a side note:please put some code next time that you have triedget

Comment: Thanks Vaibhav , but I mean in the html file , not in the java code

Comment: Use getAssets().open("filename.txt")) to get files from assets

Comment: Thanks again Vaibhav , but I don't want java code, I want to load local android assets from an html file on the server.